# anaconda mkl/openplas and IPOPT

Tags: anaconda, intel-mkl, ipopt

[IPOPT is not thread safe](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki/FAQ). In anaconda python I can opt out MKL optimizations using `conda install nomkl`. However, openblas is installed automatically instead. I was wondering, if I might run into problems or wrong results because anaconda still uses threaded versions of some underlying routines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally A is not thread safe means you should not use A in more than one thread of a single process. It does not mean that A can not use threaded libraries like MKL.

What you are worrying about is not necessary. If you are still not sure, you could run some tests/examples of IPOPT to see what happens.